# if can't access parameter in JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, module, parameters, scope, module.exports

Hi I'm having problems with the scope of an if in a JavaScript module.
Here is a mock up of my code :

```js
module.exports = {
caser(nb){
if(0 === 0){
nb = 3+2
}
}
}
```

The function is called from another JavaScript file. Nb however doesn't change when I do this.
My editor (visual studio code) marked nb as unused. This I tried :

```js
module.exports = {
caser(nb){
let number = nb
if(0 === 0){
number = 3+2
}
}
}
```

This still doesn't seem to alter the value of nb. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassigning `nb` (or `number`) will only change what those variable names point to *in the current function*. It sounds like what you need to do is *return* the changed value, and have the consumer of the function use it to reassign the value it passes in. Something like:

```
// consumer file:
const { caser } = require('./foo');

let nb = 5;
nb = caser(nb);
```

```
module.exports = {
    caser(nb) {
        if (0 === 0) {
            nb = 3 + 2
        }
        return nb;
    }
}
```

The only way to avoid having to reassign in the consumer would be for the consumer to pass an object instead, and mutate the object.

```
// consumer file:
const { caser } = require('./foo');

const objToPass = { nb: 5 };
caser(objToPass);
```

```
module.exports = {
    caser(objToPass) {
        if (0 === 0) {
            objToPass.nb = 3 + 2
        }
    }
}
```